# How to test if a formula is one-sided?

Tags: r

I need to test if a formula is one-sided (e.g. `~ a` rather than `a~b`).

Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
test <- list( ~ a + b, a ~ b + c, b + c ~ a )
isOneSided <- function(form) length(form)==2 && sum(grepl("~",form))==1
> sapply(test,isOneSided)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Is there a better way?  I'm worried there are types of formulae that I don't know about that could elude this test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use the `terms` function and extract the response attribute:

```
test <- list( ~ a + b, a ~ b + c, b + c ~ a )
sapply( test , function(x) attr( terms(x) , "response" ) == 0 )
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

### Edit

As @Arun points out `terms` can't expand a formula object with a special like `.` in it without knowing the `data.frame` that the special refers to. A workaround for this would be to include a dummy `data.frame` in the `terms` function call:

```
## If we want to expand the '.' in b + c ~ .    
test <- list( ~ a + b, a ~ b + c, b + c ~ a ,  b + c ~ . , . ~ b + c  )
sapply( test , function(x) attr( terms(x , data = data.frame(runif(1))) , "response" ) == 0 )
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this function. One question: shouldn't it work if the formula was `b + c ~ .`?

Comment: It would work if you were actually passing it as a *real* formula. `terms` can't expand the terms without knowing the dataframe that the `.` refers to. So I guess this depends on what context the formula is being tested.

Comment: @Arun I added a workaround for that. I *think* that will suffice, BUT I reckon you can probably find a way to break it!! :-)

Comment: @SimonO101 I thought I might be able to fool it with `a~0` or `0~a`, but it works.  Nicely done.

Comment: @SimonO101, how about `~ b ~ c`? I'm not sure which sided formula it is, but `attr(terms(.), "response")` gives 1.

Comment: Is that a meaningful formula? I'm not sure

Comment: @Arun My conception of "one-sided" was that it only had one side and one `~`.  This is for a formula used to sort on.  But maybe I should write a sidedness formula function instead.

Comment: @SimonO101, meaningful aside, this passes the tests. That is, the `class` function gives "formula" and "terms" give 1. So, if you should assume that your user could input such as that, is what I thought (like `0~b`). Maybe it doesn't make sense at all but what if the user gives such an input..

Comment: @AriB.Friedman, I understood that from your `grepl` code part, but I was trying to amuse Simon :).